# JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool

Tags: spring, azure, caching

I am getting this exception when trying to implement the redis cache in spring using azure redis cache.

I have configured the cacheConfig as follows,

```
 @Bean
          public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
          JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        redisConnectionFactory.setHostName("hostname");
        redisConnectionFactory.setPort(6380);
        redisConnectionFactory.setTimeout(100000);
       redisConnectionFactory.setPassword("password");
              }

          @Bean
           public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
            RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
            redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
            return redisTemplate;
          }

          @Bean
isCacheManager(redisTemplate);
         return cacheManager;
          }
```

I am using azure redis cache. But when I try to insert into the redis cache I get the following exception. I am adding the full exception stack trace.

org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:128)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:153)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.put(RedisCache.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.put(RedisCache.java:125)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doPut(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:82)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:677)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:361)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:302)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy714.insertIntoEmailStorage_RedisCache(Unknown Source)
    at com.lms.email.service.impl.EmailServiceImpl.getInboxGmail_cache(EmailServiceImpl.java:656)
    at com.lms.email.service.impl.EmailServiceImpl.getInbox(EmailServiceImpl.java:319)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy709.getInbox(Unknown Source)
    at com.lms.email.controller.EmailController.getInbox(EmailController.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.lms.utils.Authentication.doFilter(Authentication.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:16)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:155)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:239)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.auth(BinaryJedis.java:2139)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:196)
    ... 86 more
</pre></code>

Also how to set the ssl property when using the JedisConnectionFactory?

Comment: Care to post the full stack trace? Jedis truncates the real cause...

Comment: sorry @mp911de I have now posted the whole stack trace. please check. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's the overload for your Factory but you're definitely missing the TLS flag.

See this: https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/test/java/redis/clients/jedis/tests/SSLJedisTest.java#L55

**6380/TCP** is TLS enabled in Azure Redis Cache. You can enable **6379/TCP** from the Azure Portal for plain text connections or you can do the right thing.

Check out the official quickstart for Jedis with Azure Redis Cache (note the `useSsl` flag) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-java-get-started

```
JedisShardInfo shardInfo = new JedisShardInfo("
     <name>.redis.cache.windows.net", 
     6380,
     useSsl);

shardInfo.setPassword("<key>"); /* Use your access key. */
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(shardInfo);

jedis.set("foo", "bar");
String value = jedis.get("foo");
```

Comment: Thanks @evilSnobu, I tried to use JedisSharedInfo as,  JedisShardInfo shardInfo = new JedisShardInfo("hostname",6380, true);
 shardInfo.setPassword("password");  and then I put it in  connectionFactory as, redisConnectionFactory.setShardInfo(shardInfo); But it still gives the same exception as above.

Comment: The CacheConfig class returns an connectionFactory object and not an jedis object. so I set the JedisSharedInfo in connectionFactory.

Comment: Also when I tried to use a non ssl port 6379, then it gave the exception as redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisException: Could not return the resource to the pool. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalidated object not currently part of this pool. How to resolve this in spring environment with teh above CacheConfig class in the spring project?

Comment: The above exception got resolved when I used a higher version of spring data redis i.e. 1.6.1 earlier I was using 1.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error. Then i follow this link
https://github.com/Azure/azure-redis-cache-samples/blob/master/Java/ClientSamples/src/main/java/jedis/PoolUsage.java

Just to check and connect azure redis instance.

```
private static void setupPool() {
    JedisPool jedisPool = createPool(RedisClientConfig.getInstance());

    try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
        jedis.set("rahul", "Big Data Dev");
        String value = jedis.get("rahul");
        System.out.println(value);
    } catch (JedisConnectionException e) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Failed to connect to Redis server: %s", e));
        System.out.println(Utils.getSystemMetrics());
        System.out.println(Utils.getPoolUsage(jedisPool));
    } // implicitly call Jedis.close() to return instance in try clause
}
```

All the dependent class you will find in above link. Make sure your configuration on RedisClientConfig class should be correct.

**Getting Response ->Big Data Dev**